# Porque no funciona mi lista enlazada simple?

Tags: c++, lista

No se estan insertando los nodos en mi lista bien y no se porque.

Lingo es un type def de mi struct.

Asi es como inserto nodos: (me da una segmentation fault en el loop al intentar enlazar cuando ya hay al menos un nodo  )

```
void insertar(lingo *&cabeza, int value)
{
    // Creaciòn de nodo y auxiliar
    lingo *nuevo = new (lingo);

    if (cabeza != NULL) // Caso 2: Ya hay nodos,agrega al final
    {
        lingo *actual= cabeza;
         
         while (actual != NULL)
        {
            actual=actual->next; 
        }
        actual= nuevo;
        actual->number = value;
       
   
    }
    else // No hay nodos
    {
        cabeza = nuevo;
        nuevo->number = value;
       
    }
   
}
```

Ahora aqui esta la funcion para mostrar el contenido de la lista (que por cierto solo me imprime el primer elemento que ponga)

```
void mostrar(lingo *cabeza)
{
    lingo *aux1 = cabeza;

    if (aux1 != NULL)
    {
        while (aux1 != NULL)
        {
            cout << cabeza->number << endl;
            aux1 = aux1->next;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " No hay elementos para mostrar \n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En principio yo diría que el problema está aquí:

```
while (actual != NULL)
{
    actual=actual->next; 
}
actual= nuevo;
```

`actual` es un puntero, esto es una variable que almacena direcciones de memoria. La memoria direccionada por el puntero puede ser compartida, es decir, que los cambios que hagas en esa región de memoria pueden ser *vistos* por otros punteros. Sin embargo, el valor de la dirección de memoria es un dato exclusivo de esta variable. Quiero decir, si tu haces que este puntero direccione otra región de memoria, ningún otro puntero va a enterarse de ello.

Creo que es más facil verlo con variables normales:

```
int a = 5;
int b = a;
b = 3;

std::cout << a;
```

Es facil ver en este ejemplo que `a` no va a cambiar de valor por muchos cambios que realices en `b`. Esto es así porque cada variable dispone de su propia región de memoria para almacenar información.

Sin embargo, si las variables compartiesen la misma región de memoria el resultado cambiaría:

```
int a = 5;
int &b = a;
b = 3;

std::cout << a;
```

Pero esto no es lo que sucede con los punteros. Los punteros son variables como en el primer ejemplo. La única diferencia es que en vez de almacenar enteros, gestionan direcciones de memoria. Así, si dos punteros tienen almacenada la misma dirección de memoria, podrán hacer cambios en la misma región. Sin embargo, la dirección de memoria se guarda en la memoria propia de cada variable, luego este dato no se comparte:

```
int *a = (int*)0x1234;
int *b = a;
b = (int*)0x44444;

std::cout << a;
```

Si quieres modificar el `next` tienes que quedarte en el **último nodo válido**

```
while (actual->next != nullptr)
{
    actual = actual->next;
}
```

Y, claro, dado que ahora `actual` se queda apuntando al último nodo, para añadir el nuevo nodo ahora hay que hacerlo así:

```
actual->next = nuevo;
```